# C++ OOP architecture: deciding between declaring an object from a base class or inheriting the base class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I think my mind is fried at this point and I am looking for some help as to how to connect the following concern-oriented classes in C++.

**SensorBase:** 
contains a typical sensors functionality. most of the sensors share the same functionality, but some of the functions are dependent on each specific sensor class and are therefore declared "virtual" (fe `SensorBase::calcFactor()` and `SensorBase::calcCelling()` ).

**SensorThreshold & SensorTrend:** 
these classes extend the functionality of just specific bits of the SensorBase class depending on whether I want to track the current sensor reading against a "threshold level", or whether I want to track the trend of a sequence of sensor readings. They both implement differently "calcFactor()". It makes absolute sense that these classes are derived from SensorBase.

Finally, my mix up happens here:
**CO2Sensor, NH3Sensor, O2Sensor, etc:**
These are "Xgas" sensor class (will be called XSensor as a group from now on). For each sensor I may need to track the threshold, or the trend of the acquired values, or both. This statement suggests that I could declare one (or both) SensorThreshold / SensorTrend objects.

The problem (and twist) is that each XSsensor needs to redefine the SensorBase::calcCelling() function. So thinking it like this it seems that deriving XGasSensor from either SensorThreshold , or SensorTrend (as public virtual to avoid the "diamond problem") would help. But then I do not know which of SensorThreshold ::calcCelling() and SensorTrend::calcCelling() would be called. The 2 have identical implementations, but may be called with a different value as param.

If I am not mistaken, the compiler should throw an error here and abort compilation. But then, I am left with no way to implement calcCelling() from each XGasSensor.

The above is wrapped up in the following

```
class SensorBase
{
    public:
        virtual calcFactor();
        virtual calcCelling();
};

class SensorThreshold : virtual public SensorBase
{
    public:
        calcFactor();
        calcCelling();
};

class SensorTrend : virtual public SensorBase
{
    public:
        calcFactor();
        calcCelling();
};
```

Then either

```
class CO2Sensor
{
    public:
        SensorThreshold sensorThres;
        SensorTrend sensorTrend;
        //but I cannot implement calcCelling() now
};
```

or

```
class CO2Sensor: public SensorThreshold , public SensorTrend ;
{
    public:
        calcCeilling(); //this would probably be "ambigious" error by the compiler
};
```

In the end I guess the question is: how can I implement bits of SensorBase in SensorThreshold & SensorTrend and other bits in each of XGasSensor? and at the same time base my XGasSensor implementation to either SensorThreshold or SensorTrend or both?

EDIT:

The above may make a little bit more sense if I say that currently SensorThreshold and SensorTrend functionality (explained below) is part of the SensorBase class. So all XGasSensors (explained later on as well) derive the SensorBase and implement `calcCeiling()`. This way, all sensors keep track of both Thresholds and Trends and this is not ideal (as not all sensors need both Threshold tracking and trend tracking). This is why i am attempting to separate the threshold related functionality from the trend related one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without overriding `calcCeiling()` in `XSensor`, you will get an ambiguity error if you attempt to call this method on an `XSensor`.  However, you can call you can call either version of this method from `SensorThreshold` or `SensorTrend` by just qualifying it.  If you override `calcCeiling()` in `XSensor` calls to this will be unambiguous for `XSensor`

```
class CO2Sensor: public SensorThreshold , public SensorTrend
{
public:
    int calcCeiling() override {
        SensorThreshold::calcCeiling(); // this works
        SensorTrend::calcCeiling();  // this also works
    }
};

// by another object.
SensorBase* co2sensor = CreateSensor("CO2"); 
co2sensor->SensorThreshold::calcCeiling(); // non-ambiguous.
co2sensor->SensorTrend::calcCeiling(); // non-ambiguous.
co2sensor->calcCeiling(); // non-ambiguous (calls CO2Sensor::calcCeiling.)
```

I'd reconsider your inheritance model because it sounds like you're trying to add additional capabilities onto a sensor, which sounds better portrayed as a [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) than multiple inheritance.

Comment: extremely interesting (and new to me) topic of "decorator pattern" , I am thoroughly looking into it

Answer (score 1):

```
class SensorBase
{
    public:
        virtual calcFactor();
        virtual calcCelling();
};

class SensorThreshold : virtual public SensorBase
{
    public:
        calcFactor();
        Virtual calcCelling()
          {ThCeiling()}

    Protected:
          Virtual ThCeiling();
};

class SensorTrend : virtual public SensorBase
{
    public:
        calcFactor();
        Virtual calcCelling()
           {TrCeiling();}

    Protected:
        Virtual TrCeiling();
};

class CO2Sensor: public SensorThreshold , public SensorTrend ;
{
    Protected:
        TrCeiling();
        ThCeiling();
};
```

Comment: Could somebody format this? Don't know how to do it from My phone

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are saying that the CO2 sensor could implement either the Threshold or Trend functionality and that would be determined at run time when such a CO2 sensor would be created.
Therefore I would suggest an approach where the CO2 sensor would contain a pointer to the base class, which could be initialized, perhaps upon construction.

```
class CO2Sensor {
  private:
    SensorBase *sensorFunctionality;
  public:
    CO2Sensor( SensorBase *functionality);
    returnType calcCeiling() { return functionality->calcCeiling(); }
}
```

The constructor body would assign the `functionality` argument to the `sensorFunctionality` data member

It if were the case that many sensor has this multiple functionality behavior you might have a class called MultifunctionSensor, that does this dispatching and then have all MultifunctionSensor classes derive from it.